# Using a function to get the name from a email address with PHP MySQL database driven website

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, session

I have a database driven website that has a login to a member or admin area. The login says, "Welcome, Member, pat@email.com" (for example) and I want it to say - "Welcome, Member, Pat" (for example). I have a function that I know works for this, but for some reason I can't get it to work now. It is giving me this error and saying that results is NULL:

> Notice: Undefined variable: results in J:\XAMPP\htdocs\tire\admin\home.php on line 59

Below is the two different get_name functions I've tried - note that I have tried one of these and didn't have any trouble getting it to work before.

```
 function get_name($results) {
    $name = preg_split("/@/", $results['email']);
    $name = ucfirst($name[0]);
    return $name;
 }

function get_name($results) {
list($name, $email) = array_pad(explode('@', $results['name'], 2), 2, null);
  return $name;
 }
```

And here is the logout form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="logoutform.php">

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Logout</legend>

                        <?php
                    echo "Welcome, ";
                            echo $_SESSION['level']. ", ";
                            echo $_SESSION['loginName'];

                            echo get_name($results); 
                            var_dump($results);
                    ?>  <br /> <br/> <br/> <br/>
                        <input type="submit" name="action" value="logout"/>

                </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Connect function:

```
function connect($loginName) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT email, level, password FROM members WHERE email    = '$loginName'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $results = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $results;
 }
```

Comment: Where do you set `$results`?

Comment: The error is occurring in `home.php` (Read the error message) and refers to the variable `$results` (__Read__ the error message). Go look at the right file, and if you still have a problem, post the right file here.

Comment: @HoboSapiens, the form is on the home.php page.

Comment: @chris85 $results comes from a connect function. I'll edit and post the connect function.

Comment: Can't tell which code lives in what file, but if the connect() function isn't in home.php, $results isn't in scope. The easiest (and least technically correct) thing to do is move the connect() into home.php.

Comment: @SavageBits, I have a include to the functions with this function in it. Shouldn't that be just as good as having it directly in the file. Many files are using the same function. Thank you for helping!!!

Comment: An include will work if $results is declared outside of the connect() function, but if it's only used in connect(), it won't live outside of that function call. I'm assuming there are no classes involved, yeah?

Comment: @SavageBits No classes involved. I had this working at one point but it stopped and I can't get it to work now. I tried putting both functions in the same file and that still gives the error. I really need this to work!!! Your help is definitely appreciated. God bless you.

Comment: Ok, just a scope issue. Throw $results = 0; above the connect function anywhere inside <?php ...

Comment: @SavageBits I tried that and now it just gives me nothing - no error but nothing else either. Thanks tons.

Comment: Are you calling connect() first so that $results is populated with whatever is being fetched on connect()? If so, there's either another issue OR that query is returning nothing.

Comment: @SavageBits - I am putting the $results = 0; directly after the connect function and it isn't showing a error or anything when I use the get_name($results); function. It has to be something else because there is definitely results in the query. I have the results displayed but it just won't get the results with the get_name function for some reason. It honestly was working at one point and stopped. I can't recall any reason for it stopping though. Thanks!!!

Comment: K, without seeing it, here's my final thought: make sure you're setting $results BEFORE you call connect(). And make sure connect is called before you call get_name(). Since this is procedural, order is everything. Good luck!

Comment: @SavageBits THANKS for trying to  help me but it still won't work. I know it's just some little quirky thing, but I can't find it. I hope someone can figure it out!!! Thank you so much and God bless you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72072/discussion-between-regina-shepherd-riddle-and-savagebits).

Comment: Where is connect called and where is result set? Returning it doesn't set it.

Comment: What if there email address is info@gmail.com? Why not store their name when they register?